# Код телеграмм-бота не работает параллельно с кодом другой программы

Tags: telebot, opencv

Делаю программу для мониторинга свободных парковочных мест, одна из частей программы телеграмм-бот, который будет отправлять по запросу пользователя (то-есть если пользователь нажал на кнопку) кол-во свободных мест на парковке. Проблема в том, что автономно код бота корректно (отвечает на команду /start и тд) и код анализа парковки автономно корректно работает (показывает изображение с парковкой),но как только я запускаю код где есть и та, и другая часть, то перестаёт работать та часть программы, которая находится ниже по строчкам.

Сам код:

```
import cv2
import pickle
import cvzone
import numpy as np
import telebot
from telebot import types
global bot
bot = telebot.TeleBot('xxx')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Проверить кол-во свободных мест")
    markup.add(btn1)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Здравствуй!", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)

    if message.text == 'Проверить кол-во свободных мест':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Свободно {checkSpaces()} из {len(posList)} мест.',
                            reply_markup=markup)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)


cap = cv2.VideoCapture('carPark.mp4')
width, height = 90, 40
with open('CarParkPos', 'rb') as f:
    global posList
    posList = pickle.load(f)


def empty(a):
    pass


cv2.namedWindow("Vals")
cv2.resizeWindow("Vals", 640, 240)
cv2.createTrackbar("Val1", "Vals", 25, 50, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Val2", "Vals", 16, 50, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Val3", "Vals", 5, 50, empty)


def checkSpaces():
    spaces = 0
    for pos in posList:
        x, y = pos
        w, h = width, height

        imgCrop = imgThres[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        count = cv2.countNonZero(imgCrop)

        if count < 700:
            color = (0, 200, 0)
            thic = 2
            spaces += 1

        else:
            color = (0, 0, 200)
            thic = 2

        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, thic)

        cv2.putText(img, str(cv2.countNonZero(imgCrop)), (x, y + h - 6), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1,
                    color, 2)

    cvzone.putTextRect(img, f'Free: {spaces}/{len(posList)}', (50, 60), thickness=3, offset=20,
                       colorR=(0, 200, 0))
    return(spaces)


while cap.isOpened():

    # Get image frame
    success, img = cap.read()
    if cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) == cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT):
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)
    # img = cv2.imread('img.png')
    imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    imgBlur = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgGray, (3, 3), 1)
    # ret, imgThres = cv2.threshold(imgBlur, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    val1 = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Val1", "Vals")
    val2 = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Val2", "Vals")
    val3 = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Val3", "Vals")
    if val1 % 2 == 0: val1 += 1
    if val3 % 2 == 0: val3 += 1
    imgThres = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(imgBlur, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                                     cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, val1, val2)
    imgThres = cv2.medianBlur(imgThres, val3)
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
    imgThres = cv2.dilate(imgThres, kernel, iterations=1)

    checkSpaces()
    # Display Output

    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    # cv2.imshow("ImageGray", imgThres)
    # cv2.imshow("ImageBlur", imgBlur)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('r'):
        pass
```

Comment: Используйте `threading` чтобы запустить что либо в отдельном потоке